# Angular 2 - Navigating to user details page doesn't show selected user details

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-promise, angular2-observables

I'm trying to create a user detail page where you get more information about the selected user.
When you click on a user name from the list, it navigates to the user details page succesfully but throws this error:

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in src/person-details.component.html:3:25 caused by: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Here is a plunk:
http://embed.plnkr.co/cUEIag77etv95ZFJY3iN/

and here are the codes:

person-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { IPerson } from './person';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  templateUrl: 'src/person-list.component.html'
})

export class PersonListComponent implements OnInit {

  _persons: IPerson[];
  selectedPerson: IPerson;

  constructor(
    private _appService: AppService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._appService.getPersons()
      .subscribe(
      _persons => this._persons = _persons); // set our local _persons array equal to the IPerson[] data which arrive from our data stream
  }

  goToDetails(person: IPerson): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/user', person.id])
  }
}
```

person-list.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class='table-responsive'>
    <table class='table'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let person of _persons" (click)="goToDetails(person)" class="row">
          <td>{{person.id}}</td>
          <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

person-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { IPerson } from './person';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-details',
  templateUrl: 'src/person-details.component.html'
})

export class PersonDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _appService: AppService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => { // delivers our array of route parameters.
      let id = +params['id']; // The person id is a number. Route parameters are always strings. So we convert the route parameter value to a number with the JavaScript (+) operator.
      this._appService.getPerson(id)
        .map(person => this.person = person);
    });
  }

  // navigates backward one step in the browser's history stack using the Location service we injected 
  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

person-details.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Person Details</h3>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div><span>Id:</span> {{person.id}}</div>
    <div><span>Name:</span> {{person.name}}</div>
    <div><span>Description:</span> {{person.description}}</div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; // required for getting persons from JSON file
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; // required by the .map method

import { IPerson } from './person';

@Injectable() export class AppService {

    private _personUrl = 'src/persons.json';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { } // required to Inject Http as a dependency. Creates a private _http variable and assigns the injected service instance to that variable

    getPersons(): Observable<IPerson[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._personUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <IPerson[]>response.json().personData); // we let the compiler know that the array contains items of type 'IPerson' and return the 'personData' object from the json file as an array
    }

    // filters the person list from getPersons by id
    getPerson(id: number): Observable<IPerson> {
        return this.getPersons()
            .map(persons => persons.find(person => person.id === id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the PersonDetailsComponent is initialized the field person is null and thar causes an error on the template bindings. You can replace the template bindings to account for that using `field?.subfield`.

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Person Details</h3>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div><span>Id:</span> {{person?.id}}</div>
    <div><span>Name:</span> {{person?.name}}</div>
    <div><span>Description:</span> {{person?.description}}</div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

I edited your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GrIC2qc4TbZcJOrmM1yi?p=preview) to a version with these changes. I also needed to edit the PersonDetailsComponent to subscribe to the getPerson() observable.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. The Elvis operator only solves the problem in the console. What I'm looking trying to achieve is to show the selected user information, but the "person" property is undefined for some reason.

Comment: Ok, Got it! I've forgot to subscribe to the Observable. btw the elvis operators are not required to get this working. Thanks again!

Comment: @GuilhermeMeireles Refering to src/person-details.component.ts on line 25 it says that this.person, in my case, that the property is not found. Did you forgot a person: Person; declaration in the beginning?

Comment: @Lobato Yeap. Added a "person: any" now. thks.